# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Integer to T

Tags: java, casting, warnings

How can fix unchecked cast from Integer to T? Im getting this warning in this line:

```
undoStackIndexes.push((T)index);
```

The code:

```
SimpleStack<T> undoStackIndexes = new SimpleStack<T>();
SimpleStack<T> undoStackDatas = new SimpleStack<T>();
public void add( int idx, T x ){
        Node<T> p = getNode( idx, 0, size( ) );
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>( x, p.prev, p );
        newNode.prev.next = newNode;
        p.prev = newNode;         
        theSize++;
        modCount++;

        undoStackDatas.push(newNode.data);
        Integer index = new Integer(idx);
        undoStackIndexes.push((T)index);
    }
```

Comment: why are you making `undoStackIndexes` generic in `T`? isn't it just `Integer` indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you're going to store `Integer` indexes in your `undoStackIndexes` stack you shouldn't make it generic with `T` type:

```
SimpleStack<Integer> undoStackIndexes = new SimpleStack<Integer>();
```